# Calculate DRAM latency

Tags: timing, latency, dram

I am trying to make some performance on a memory centric network which has one cpu and multiple memory cubes.(HMC)

I want to calculate the intra HMC latency which means the latency between sending a request to one memory cube and receiving the response. This latency is based on DRAM timings which I should use to calculate the total latency. Let's say I have the DRAM timings which are indicated in the picture below.

Could anyone help me in calculating the total dram latency for a read and write request(each of them is 64B)?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assigment. Try to show some work or what you have tried, or what part in calculating the dram latency you are struggeling with, or this *will* be closed

Comment: @JorenVaes I have edited and explained more. thanks

Comment: The number of cycles per transaction varies depending on whether a row is already open (how many can be open is DRAM type dependent). This is one of the reasons that assessing DRAM latency is difficult; you need to show your use case in detail and the specific type of DRAM.

Comment: But you have not shown where you are stuck or even if you understand what the DRAM Interface Timing parameters mean.  We don't do your homework!  Show some effort and someone will help, but we do not do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @PeterSmith well this is not a home work, I am actually working on a paper. The policy is closed page which means the row must be activated for each request even for the same row.

Comment: @Arghaven: I did not say or imply this is homework. Closed page policies are (mostly) deterministic and take a complete RAS-CAS-Transaction cycle; don't overlook refresh cycles stealing some time. The actual time per bus cycle should fairly straightforward to compute from the data sheet.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: I completely agree; I have provided what I believe to be sufficient information for the OP to figure it out for themselves.